# Adding dependency for Jira plugin

Tags: java, maven, jira, jira-plugin

With the SDK 6.3.10, I am trying to develop a plugin for Jira 7.x.

This plugin should use an external Java dependency named "svnkit". I added it as dependency in the pom (this should be enough if I understood https://developer.atlassian.com/server/framework/atlassian-sdk/managing-dependencies/ correctly):

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.svnkit</groupId>
  <artifactId>svnkit</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Now I get the message in the `atlas-run` logs:

```
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 2018-07-04 16:50:55,310 http-nio-2990-exec-3 ERROR anonymous 1010x2x1 - 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 /secure/DemoAction!default.jspa [c.a.j.web
.dispatcher.JiraWebworkActionDispatcher] Exception thrown from action 'DemoAction!default', returning 404
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] WebworkConfigurationNotFoundException{class=class webwork.config.XMLActionConfiguration, message='No such view mapping', name='Dem
oAction.actionRoles.actionRoles'}
```

The plugin itself returns a 404 page in the browser. Without the svnkit, everything works in the browser. Note that I have not used svnkit in the Java code.

I haven't got the slightest clue what this message means or where I such search for a remedy.

Comment: First based on the page plugins of JIRA are OSGi bundles which means adding a dependency in the pom is **not** enough which means you have to add information about in the MANIFEST.MF file as well..but I'm not 100%sure...

Comment: This is what I try to understand - I know that using other plugins/bundles requires import-package statements, but is this true for "plain" dependencies? I also tried to write a proper import but it not solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to know exactly where and when the `svnkit` library to be used, and what is the purpose this library in your project. With the information you provide, I can only distantly guide you to the right solution.

In JIRA/OSGI world you have basically two options:

1. You compile the library together with your code so that bytecode of your project and bytecode of library you used got packed together into JAR file as a result of `atlas-package` (`mvn package`). I skipped any other resources for clarity.
2. You compile your project but final JAR contains only bytecode of your project plus explicit information that the dependent library will already be present in the environment that the JAR was launched.

In your case, I presume `svnkit` library is not present in JIRA that you want to run your plugin/JAR. That mean, you need to provide it by yourself. The pretty/recommended way is to:

1. Prepare `svnkit` to be OSGI ready, the JAR needs to be valid OSGI bundle. (You can find such bundle already prepared somewhere in Atlassian maven repository or somewhere in the Internet)
2. In your pom.xml add this dependency with scope `provided`: eg.:

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.svnkit</groupId>
       <artifactId>svnkit</artifactId>
       <version>1.1.0</version>
       <scope>provided</scope>
   </dependency>
   ```
3. Add configuration for `maven-amps-plugin` (`maven-jira-plugin`) to pack `svnkit` as an OSGI bundle dependency

   ```
   <build>
       <plugins>
           <plugin>
               <groupId>com.atlassian.maven.plugins</groupId>
               <artifactId>maven-jira-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>${amps.version}</version>
               <configuration>
                   <extractDependencies>false</extractDependencies>
                   <pluginDependencies>
                       <pluginDependency>
                           <groupId>...</groupId>
                           <artifactId>...</artifactId>
                       </pluginDependency>
                   </pluginDependencies>
               ...
               </configuration>
           </plugin>
       </plugins>
   </build>
   ```

   In that way `atlas-package` will produce also an OBR file which will contain your project JAR plus `svnkit` bundle
   See also:
   https://developer.atlassian.com/server/framework/atlassian-sdk/bundling-extra-dependencies-in-an-obr/

And be warned that this:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.svnkit</groupId>
        <artifactId>svnkit</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

means exactly the same as:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.svnkit</groupId>
        <artifactId>svnkit</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

which means that `svnkit` will be included in your JAR straight or as sub-JAR (JAR in JAR)

Your logs, on the other hand, points out that you have misconfigured your `DemoAction`. It would be better if you provide `pom.xml` together with `atlassian-plugin.xml` to let us better understand your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your ideas. I hoped to get around bundling the external dependency in OSGi manner. What is the practical difference between adding an OSGi bundle and a plain dependency? Are the dependencies of my dependency properly isolated if I use a bundle?

Comment: Practical difference: you can dynamically add/remove your dependency to JIRA this is true even for upgrade/downgrade version of your dependency. Your dependency (the version) could be then managed independently of your project. Whats more, your project's JAR will be lighter (size) and each package will take a bit less time. To the second question: Yes, the dependency will be isolated by OSGI container mainly via class loader separation, but there are more aspects to tell which cannot be resolved in one simple sentence.